# How to set metadata field in HDFS and retrieve with that field

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm having a use case in which I need to store files corresponding to an index(lucene-type) into a file system. I'm considering ***HDFS*** for the same. Whether it's possible to add a field specific to index documents into metadata of hadoop and retrieve file with that Id field later on ? I know this can be done using naming strategy. Although I don't want to add ID field to name of the file. Is there any other solution for this ?